# XCode 4.6 - Can't click the Entitlements checkbox for iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I have an iOS project that I have been working on for some time. I need to add entitlements. When I select my Target and check the "Entitlements" checkbox, it automatically un-checks it's self about 1 second later.

I have an .entitlements file in my project. I have removed it and recreated it. I have tried checking the "Entitlements" checkbox with and without the .entitlements file there.

I'm not sure what other details I need to provide to illustrate this issue, so if I have left anything out that may be important, please let me know.

Comment: This is a development question and better to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: You might explicitly list what console logs you examined to see if an error condition was logged by Xcode as it reversed your check mark.

Comment: Do you have both a development and a distribution certificate in your keychain?

Comment: Questioner unresponsive.

Comment: I'm sorry I was out on the question. Matt I do have both development and distribution certificates in the key chain.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out the resolution. 
What I had to do was remove and delete the entitlements file from my project, then go to both the Project's Build Settings tab and the Target Build Settings tab and remove all references to my .entitlements file. After this I closed XCode and re-opened it. At this point I was able to click the "Use Entitlements" checkbox.

I am sorry for not returning to this question earlier.